# facet_wrap on a nudged variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

With lots of overlapping data to show, it can be helpful to jitter points so they can be better identified. For discrete (not necessarily `factor`) data it can be helpful to offset the entire series slightly. This can now be done quite neatly using `ggplot2::position_nudge()`. As far as I can tell, that function does not accept NSE variables from the `ggplot()` call, so (and by all means correct me if I'm wrong) one needs to specify the data source if providing a variable offset from some data structure.

If, say, we want to nudge a value by an amount dependent on another value, we could do it this way:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(am)), 
             position = position_nudge(y = 0.1*mtcars$am))
p
```

[image]

Trying to use just `am` in the `position_nudge()` call fails (`"non-numeric argument to binary operator"`). Otherwise this is acceptable.

The problem with this is that `facet_wrap` on such a call breaks the effect since, presumably, the faceting code knows nothing about this explicit data

```
p + facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image]

Is there a way to allow this to happen (short of converting to continuous, shifting manually, then relabelling axis), or a more suitable function? If nothing comes up I'll raise an issue in the repo, but I figured I should consult the hivemind first.

Comment: Use eipi10's hack and file a feature req. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-nudge.R#L40 & even if if was `aes()`-able, https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-.r#L69-L72 has no code to handle the facet groups.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Does that mean such a feature request is impractical or just that it's a big ask?

Comment: I'm not sure any of the folks that are familiar with the internals of ggplot2 have cycles to "fix" (enhance?) this. You have an alternative besides epi10's code in that you could make a function to build the facets out with `dplyr::group_by()` & `::do()` and feed the resultant list column to `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`. A bit of up front work, but will give you more granular control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on the discussion in the comments, maybe the best approach is to just add fake data in a location outside the plot area so that all factor levels will have at least one data point. This will result in every point being dodged in every facet. For example:

First, we'll add data points for all unique values of all variables that will become factors in the plot, but we'll assign them an `mpg` value of -1, which is outside the plot area of the real data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(dplyr)

mtcars = bind_rows(mtcars, 
                   expand.grid(mpg=-1, 
                               cyl=unique(mtcars$cyl), 
                               am=unique(mtcars$am), 
                               gear=unique(mtcars$gear)))
```

Now we can plot with vertical dodging as in the original answer, but all points will be dodged:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(am)), position = position_dodgev(0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~gear) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=range(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg>0]))
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

You can use `position_dodge` if you switch your `x` and `y` aesthetics, and then add `coord_flip` to put `cyl` back on the vertical axis:

```
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(am)), position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```
p + facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image]

Another, option is to use `position_dodgev` from the `ggstance` package, which provides vertical dodging, and avoids the need to flip the axes:

```
library(ggstance)

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(am)), position = position_dodgev(0.3))
```

Although it's unnecessary, something like your original method could work if you do it inside `aes` so that all the ggplot components know about the mapping. For example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl + 0.2*(am - mean(am)))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(am))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=unique(mtcars$cyl), minor_breaks=NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~ gear)
```

Comment: `ggstance::position_dodgev` seems to do _most_ of what I was trying to achieve, albeit not linked to the actual variable and it doesn't dodge when there's nothing to dodge, so it loses some consistency. I'm avoiding `coord_flip` as there's much more going on in my actual code.

Comment: My actual use-case is three temperatures; `high`, `med`, `low` so I was going for above/on/below the category group. With `dodge` in cases where there are only two levels present, I get e.g. `med` below and `high` above.

Comment: Well, maybe my third option is what you need after all. Let me know.

Comment: As for the `aes()` option, that was exactly what I was trying to avoid doing.

Comment: I don't particularly like the last option, but it seems like the most "natural" way of subverting the usual ggplot workflow in that it takes advantage of the aesthetic mapping system to ensure that the hacky dodging method is inherited by all the plot components.

Comment: I'm going to let this ferment for a day, but in lieu of any better suggestions I'll accept this as it is stuffed full of helpful options. It does appear that there's no *good* way to do this, but these are many next-best ways.